# Sort table column from link outside of table

Tags: javascript, datatables

Trying to link text (from outside the table) that sorts a column and places the user to a specific spot inside the table (with a anchor tag)

So far my only solution is to refresh the entire page with

Having to refresh the page every time is a pain for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library to do this work, like Datatables with ajax data source, see the example here: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Or you may use a native way like bellow (considering to store your data on a file like the data variable):

```
    <table id="dataTable">
        <tr>
            <th><a onclick="sortTableAsc('COUNTRY')">COUNTRY</a></th>
            <th><a onclick="sortTableAsc('LoC')">LOCATION</a></th>
            <th><a onclick="sortTableAsc('BALANCE')">BALANCE</a></th>
            <th><a onclick="sortTableAsc('DATE')">DATE</a></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>

        var data = [
            { "COUNTRY": "UK", "LoC": "London", "BALANCE": "78,573", "DATE": "1/06/2018" },
            { "COUNTRY": "US", "LoC": "New York", "BALANCE": "43,568", "DATE": "18/05/2018" },
            { "COUNTRY": "PL", "LoC": "Sao Paulo", "BALANCE": "12,362", "DATE": "22/06/2018" },
            { "COUNTRY": "AU", "LoC": "Chicago", "BALANCE": "7,569", "DATE": "1/07/2018" }
        ];

        var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');

        function sortTableAsc(field) {
            if (field != undefined && field != null)
                data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a[field] > b[field]) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if (a[field] < b[field]) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                });

            table.querySelectorAll("tr.data").forEach(function(element){ element.remove(); });

            data.forEach(function (object) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr.className = 'data';
                tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + object.COUNTRY + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + object.LoC + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + object.BALANCE + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + object.DATE + '</td>';
                table.appendChild(tr);
            });
        }

        sortTableAsc(null);
    </script>
```

You may see this running here: https://jsfiddle.net/g31ou46m/1/